# How to reset versions in Package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have about 20 react projects, all of which have package.json files. I have packages like this in them:

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58",
"@material-ui/styles": "4.11.4",
```

I need to go through every single one line and update them to "0.0.0". Is there a regex that can match `"***.***.***"` and replace it with "0.0.0" ?

Reason why I need to do this:
I create my own packages. I moved them from one location to another, so their versions started from 0 all over again. If I do npm check updates, and package is 5.8.34 for example, it won't update it back to 0.0.1. But if I update all of their values to 0.0.0 then run npm check updates it'll update to 0.0.1.

Also, why anyone would be voting -1 here? Don't like the question or don't know the answer? I provided all I need to accomplish here and Below are some Regex I attempted. Why would you still vote -1?

I tried:
`: "[0-9].+?"`

So far this does the best job
`: "[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"`

It won't find ones that have letters in package name such as `"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58"`. If anyone shares a better solution I'll update the question.

This is purely a question how to reset versions of Packages in Package.json file to 0.0.0.

Comment: Why do you have to change them to "0.0.0"?

Comment: I create my own packages. I moved them from one location to another, so their versions started from 0 all over again. If I do npm check updates, and package is 5.8.34 for example, it won't update it back to 0.0.1. But if I update all of their values to 0.0.0 then run npm check updates it'll update to 0.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the packages start with a digit followed by a dot and word characters which can optionally have a hyphen in between the word characters, you can use a capture group and use that in the replacement.

Pattern:

```
("[^\s"]+":\s*")\d+(?:\.\w+(?:-\w+)*)+",
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1** (denoted by `$1` in the example code)

  - `"[^\s"]+":\s*"` Match from `"..."` then `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match a `.` 1+ word chars and optionally `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `",` Match a double quote and comma

Replace with

```
$10.0.0",
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YrWvJK/1)

```js
const regex = /("[^\s"]+":\s*")\d+(?:\.\w+(?:-\w+)*)+",/;
[
  `"@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",`,
  `"@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",`,
  `"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58",`,
  `"@material-ui/styles": "4.11.4",`
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, `$10.0.0",`)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
: "[0-9].+?"
```

to

```
: "0.0.0"
```

should be about enough (and shouldn't match too many things, but surely you'll check before committing your changes...)

Comment: This is matching this too tho `: "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16"`

Comment: it also matches `: "0px"`

Comment: Maybe limit your search-and-replace to package.jsons :)